# I have panda array which was originally a csv file. I would like to remove a specific word from all the rows in the column: text

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the panda array:

```
id          text                                       spam
4016        Subject: re : vacation vince : i just found ... 0
4017        Subject: re : receipts from visit jim , than... 0
4018        Subject: re : enron case study update wow ! a...0
4019        Subject: re : interest david , please , call... 0
4020        Subject: news : aurora 5 . 2 update aurora ve...0
```

I would like to remove the word "Subject" in the column "text" from all the rows so it becomes:

```
id          text                                       spam
4016        re : vacation vince : i just found ...  0
4017        re : receipts from visit jim , than...  0
4018        re : enron case study update wow ! a...0
4019        re : interest david , please , call...  0
4020        news : aurora 5 . 2 update aurora ve...0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.text = df.text.apply(lambda row: row[9:])
```

Each row will be changed at column "text" where the first 9 characters "Subject: " are removed.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) - `^` means start of each string and `\s+` one or more whitespaces:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].replace('^Subject:\s+', '', regex=True)
print (df)
     id                                     text  spam
0  4016   re : vacation vince : i just found ...     0
1  4017   re : receipts from visit jim , than...     0
2  4018  re : enron case study update wow ! a...     0
3  4019   re : interest david , please , call...     0
4  4020  news : aurora 5 . 2 update aurora ve...     0
```

But if need remove first `9` chars including `whitespace`s:

```
df['text'] = df['text'].str[9:]
```